# After using css to indent paragraphs site wide, how do I exclude centered text from this rule?

Tags: html, css

I have used css to indent every parapgraph in wordpress by 30px. This was going great until I noticed that it also indented my centered aligned text by 30px. That makes this centered text off centered. It's even more noticible when I look at it on mobile and I want the text to be easy and professional to read on the go. So, I want to exclude "text-align:center;" from the 30px indents for every center aligned text.

I don't have access to the entire code of my theme with my wordpress premium account. I can only edit the css using a blank css editor in a menu option. Is this possible without being able to see the whole code?

I have tried looking this up on stackoverflow before posting and using this code...

```
#article p {
    display: block;
    text-align:center;
    text-indent:0!important;
}
```

I now know that this "#workskin p.chapter" ID selector will not work because I have not added it to my code because I do not have access to the full themes code.

This is the css code that I am using to make the indents and the only code that I have in my css editor for wordpress "p" paragraph element...

```
article p {
    text-indent: 30px;
}
```

I could not get any changes in making my indents disappear for the text that was center aligned.

I'd like to make my center aligned text centered with my site and not indented an extra 30px from the center. For example:

- Title-centered with no indents
- Paragraph one-indented
- Paragraph two-indented
- Break in paragraph-centered no indents
- Paragraph three-indented
- Paragraph four-indented
- Break in paragraph-centered with no indents...etc

This is the first time I am using css. Usually I have a full theme to look at the code and I am able to make small edits using color# and changing the src of images but that is the extent of my coding knowledge and I'm learning a little more with each google search and comment. This is the last code edit I need on my site and I appreciate everyones comments and help.

Comment: Try putting important on the `text-align:center` instead of adding a text-indent: 0. So `text-align: center !important;`

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve], so we can see how it doesn't work. A CSS fragment is not enough.

Comment: I only have access to a blank css block in my wordpress menu. The only css I have for the paragraph element is the "article p" for the 30px indents. I do not have any options to see my type selector or the full wordpress code to make changes. Is it possible to make edits with just this information or is it just stabbing in the dark? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

you can put class on the p that you want to exclude from it like:

```css
article p {
    text-indent: 30px;
}

// try changing it to this remember exclude is class on p tags you want to exclude
// Dont forget the dot (.) before exclude
// and the !important is after the value
article .exclude {
    text-indent: 10px !important; // you put !important here
    color: red !important; // like this
    padding: 10px !important; // like this
}
```

**MAKE SURE TO MAKE EXCLUDED P UNDER THE NONE EXCLUDED TO REWRITE IT**
**LOOK AT CODE COMMENTS CAREFULLY**

Hope it was hepfull

Comment: Thank you for your response! I added the new code right under the original text-indent css. Even after changing the value of the text-indent and removing the "." from "article p. exclude," I am not getting any changes in the format of my text. I'll keep on working at it.

Comment: are you writing it article p. exclude? you need to remove the space article p.exclude, or even better  article exclude only and put important on it.

Comment: I added article "p.exclude" without the space and "article exclude !important" with and without the space between the "e" in exclude and the "!" with no luck. Also, I tried to look up how that class selector worked but the closest I got was with ":not()"? Thanks for your information, gives me a lot to think about and try!

Comment: Its not "article exclude !important" its: "article .exclude" dont forget the dot (.) before exclude, and the !important on the property like : color: red !important;

Answer (score 0):

The specificity in CSS is in the order of 
Type selector(h1, p ,div...) < Class selector(rules with a period .) < ID selector(rules with #) but the rules defined with `! important`  overrides any other declaration ofcourse ;)
As discussed above if different set of rules are added for a same element i.e rules targeting elements with same specificity then the CSS will use the rules defined later on (i.e the latest one) 
Example:

```
    p{
        color : red ;
    }
    p{
        color : green ;
    }
```

In this example the color of the text in paragraphs will be green and not red as rule with green color is defined after the red one.

```
    p{
        color : red ! important;
    }
    p{
        color : green ;
    }
```

But here because of `! important`is added to red the color of text inside the `p` will be red.

So in your case you can go with either defining the `text-align: center ! important` or just define the rules overiding the ones you don't want in the specific `p tag` but this can be done by defining it's specific CSS rules *after the rules for normal `p` tags*

first define the normal or default rules as

```
article p { 
    text-indent: 30px; 
    }
```

After this add the specific rules

```
#worskin p .chapter {
    display: block;
    text-align:center; 
    text-indent:0; 
    }
```

*Thanks AuxTaco for your suggestion.*

Comment: I meant this for the same elements target more than once.... in that case the rules defined later on works overriding the earlier one. Thanks for your kind suggestion @AuxTaco

Comment: Thanks for the information, this helped me get a better understanding of where to look. I think my problem is in the second half with the ID  selector. It doesn't want to add the rules to the "#workskin p. chapter" because I merely copied and pasted it from another example. Adding "text-align: center ! important" also didn't change anything but I think it also has to do with the ID selector not being right. Adding "article p" to the second part for the specific rules just makes my whole text centered AND indented. It was something I tried myself with no luck, I still have a learning curve.